# md-ink-ripple effect for specific row in a table

Tags: angular-material

I have a table and i want to have ink and ripple effect for specific row in the table. when i add the attribute md-ink-ripple to tr element of table, it shows the ripple for entire table. please let me know how to fix this issue.

Comment: I think this is not gonna work because it adds a absolute positioned `div` with class `md-ripple-container` to the `tr` element which is invalid html anyway. The closest you can get IMO is applying `md-ink-ripple` to the `td` element as in http://codepen.io/z00bs/pen/QNxeWd.

Answer (score 4):

You can add `display: block; position: relative;` to the row styling - but that can result in odd behavior.